# Java "cannot find or load main class" when trying to run on command line

Tags: java

I have a java project with the directory structure as follows:

```
java 
   | build
   | src
     | gui
         |  Launcher.java
```

I am compiling the program to a .class file using the command:

```
find -name "*.java" > src.txt
javac -d build @src.txt
rm $src.txt
```

After compilation the project directory looks like this

```
java 
   | build
     | gui
        |   Launcher.class 
   | src
     | gui
         |  Launcher.java
```

When I try to run the program (main is in Launcher.java) with:

```
java -cp .:build:**/*.class gui.Launcher
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class gui.Launcher
```

Anyone see whats wrong?

note: I am using cygwin on windows for this

Comment: Java isn't a cygwin process, so it doesn't understand that ':' is the path separator. Try using the Windows path separator ';' and you should be better off.

Comment: When I try that I get the error: "bash: build:**/*.class: No such file or directory"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that `**/*.class` is not an expression that Java understands (and cygwin may try to interpret it, replacing it with other values Java won't understand). Try just: `java -cp .;build gui.Launcher`

Comment: now it says "bash: build: command not found"...

Comment: oohh, right, you'll need to put the classpath in quotes so that bash doesn't interpret the ';', like this: `java -cp '.;build' gui.Launcher`

Comment: my homie, you killed it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Because your classpath syntax is off.

```
java -cp .:build:**/*.class gui.Launcher
```

should be (on Unix)

```
java -cp .:build/ gui.Launcher
```

or (on Windows)

```
java -cp .;build/ gui.Launcher
```

Comment: when I try the first option, I get the same error. And when I try the second option I get an error saying build/ is a directory

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct for Linux/Unix and for Windows (without Cygwin). However, when working with Java from Cygwin there's a mismatch in that Cygwin is trying to act like Linux/Unix, but Java is a Windows binary and so it doesn't understand the Linux/Unix path syntax.

Here's what you need to do when running `java` (or `javac`) with a class path from Cygwin. First use a semicolon as the path separator, and second put the whole path in quotes:

```
java -cp 'some/directory;path/to/file.jar;etc' main.class.Name <arguments>
```

Note that you can also try using the `cygpath` utility to convert a Linux/Unix style path to a Windows format that Java can understand.